# ¿Cómo extraer formula a texto en hoja de cáculo de google?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

En la celda `A1` tego la fórmula `=25/26`, para verla como texto la copio y la pego en `B1` agregando una comilla al principio `'=25/26`.

¿Con cual función puedo hacer esto automáticamente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualmente las hojas de cálculo de Google no tienen un función incluída (built-in) para obtener la formula de otra celda pero puedes usar Google Apps Script para crear una función personalizada que lo haga.

Ejemplo:

```
/**
 * Devuelve la fórmula de la referencia especificada
 *
 * @param {string} reference Referencia en formato "A1"
 * @customfunction
 */
function getFormula(reference) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
                       .getRange(reference).getFormula();
}
```

Referencia

- [Lista de funciones de las Hojas de Cálculo de Google](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=es)

Comment: Funciona con =getFormula("A1"), ¿Que tocaría hacer para que funcionara así: =getFormula(A1), de tal forma que se pudiera aplicar arrastrando y soltando a varias celdas?

Comment: Hay muchas formas de lograr eso. Puedes usar la función [DIRECCION](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=es) en conjunto con [FILA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=es) y [COLUMNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=es) o bien puedes modificar el script, pero el espacio de comenatrios es demasiado limitado para explicarlo, considera publicar una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada en inglés: [passing cell references to spreadsheet functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12206399/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

Adaptación de [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116479/1184) para que en lugar de funcionar con `=getFormula("A1")` funcione con `=getFormula('Hoja 1'!A1)` de tal forma que se pueda aplicar arrastrando y soltando a varias celdas.

```
/**
 * Devuelve la fórmula de la referencia especificada
 *
 * @param {'Hoja 1'!A1} reference Referencia en 'Nombre Hoja'!Celda
 * @customfunction
 */
function getFormula(reference) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formulaCelda1 = sheet.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var celda2 = formulaCelda1.match(/=\w+\((.*)!(.*)\)/i)[2];
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(celda2).getFormula();
}
```

[Ver ejemplo de referencia.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37970643/4564845)